# QML - Why does TabBar's implicitWidth depend on binding inner TabButton's width to its implicitWidth?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt5.15

Why in the following code `implicitWidth` of `TabBar` changes when I comment out `width: implicitWidth` in `TabButton`s? Why does the fact that I am setting `width` of a component to be equal to its `implicitWidth` change the `implicitWidth`?
Also, I thought `width` was set to `implicitWidth` by default anyways when `width` is not explicitly set. So I don't understand why doing `width: implicitWidth` would have any effects. Here is the code:

```
Item {
   id: root
   height: 480
   width: 640

   RowLayout {
      anchors.fill: parent

      TabBar {
         id: bar
         Layout.fillHeight: true
         implicitWidth: Math.max(homeTabButton.implicitWidth, discoverTabButton.implicitWidth, activityTabButton.implicitWidth)

         background: Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
         }

         contentItem: ListView {
            model: bar.contentModel
         }


         TabButton {
            id: homeTabButton
            width: implicitWidth // I cannot comment this out
            text: qsTr("Home")
         }
         TabButton {
            id: discoverTabButton
            width: implicitWidth // I cannot comment this out
            text: qsTr("Discover")
         }
         TabButton {
            id: activityTabButton
            width: implicitWidth // I cannot comment this out
            text: qsTr("Activity")
         }
      }

      StackLayout {
         Layout.fillWidth: true
         Layout.fillHeight: true
         currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
         Pane {
            id: homeTab
            background: Rectangle {
               color: "blue"
            }
         }
         Pane {
            id: discoverTab
            background: Rectangle {
               color: "red"
            }
         }
         Pane {
            id: activityTab
            background: Rectangle {
               color: "green"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The `implicitWidth` is like the `sizeHint`'s width of a widget. A hint might be taken into consideration or not. `Width` is the actual width.

Comment: @user6528273 But why would setting the `width` to `implicitWidth` change `implicitWidth`?

Answer (score 0):

U have assigned an implicit width before

```
implicitWidth: Math.max(homeTabButton.implicitWidth, discoverTabButton.implicitWidth, activityTabButton.implicitWidth)
```

that's why when u comment width in tabButton it taking width as 0.

use

```
width: Math.max(homeTabButton.implicitWidth, discoverTabButton.implicitWidth, activityTabButton.implicitWidth)
```

in your code and comment that width in tabButton ans see.

Comment: The `implicitWidth` that I have assigned before is for the `bar` component, the `implicitWidth` I use for each TabButton is that specific button's `implicitWidth`. What you have is not good practice in my opinion as it's recommended to always refer to parent size in children's size and to children's implicit size in parent's implicit size to have reusable components.